# How can I work with a hidden viewer by css?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm currently working with a forge viewer that appears in a modal (dialog), so at the beginning it's hidden and I got message errors, and model not load:

```
<section id="modal" style="display: none">
  <div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/xqjfet1k/

[image]

It's ok if I start with the viewer not hidden:

https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/xqjfet1k/16/

Any suggestions How I could work with viewer in modals?
Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide Viewer without breaking the app for rendering to a zero sized canvas (which we do have plans to support in future versions but not sure exactly when), the easiest way would be to set the `visibility` of the container to `hidden` (so that it'd be still rendered but without any visibility in the viewport)

```
#ViewerContainer{
visibility:hidden
}
```

Check it out in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jv15db8g/)

Comment: Hi Bryan,
any news to support rendering to a zero sized canvas? I am trying to lazy load the model, whereas the user can choose to fade in the viewer anytime.
I tried:
- display: none -> zero sized canvas problem
- position absolute outside of the visible screen -> Model is not visible when the viewer is finally shown (viewer.hideModel(id) + viewer.showModel(id) makes the model visible). Doesnt work everytime.
- visabilty: hidden -> There is still some space on my screen occupied by the container of the viewer.
Any idea how to solve this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you